# How many 4-element DNA sequences containg exactly three of four bases A,T,C,G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

```
How many 4-element DNA sequences containg exactly three of four bases A,T,C,G?

Hello, my answer is c(4,3)*c(3,1)*(4!/2!) because

by saying c(4,3), I choose three of four bases, e.g. ATC_
by saying c(3,1), I choose extra one of chosen three bases, e.g. ATCT
by saying 4!/2!, I permutated them, i.e., there is 4!/2! possible permutations of ATCT.
```

So, I found the answer as 144, but there is a solution on the internet like this:

```
The objective is to find the 4 element DNA sequence that contain exactly three of the four bases A, C, G, and T.
Three of the four bases, but not with base A.
There are 3 ways for first base as it cannot be A.
There are 3 ways for second base as it cannot be A.
There are 2 ways for third base as it cannot be A and nor first or second base.
There are 1 way for fourth base as it cannot be A and nor first or second or third base.
By product rule, 3.3.2.1 =18.
Exactly three of four bases.
As there are 4 possible bases that are excluded and there are 18 DNA sequences without corresponding base but with three of the four bases.
By product rule, 4.18 = 72.
Therefore, there are 72 possible way for 4 DNA bases.
```

I wonder which answer is correct 144 or 72? and if my solution with the answer 144 is correct, then why is the solution on the internet with answer 72 incorrect? or if my solution is incorrect, then why?

Comment: Where does the "solution on the internet" come from?

Comment: Pick one base $4\choose 1$ to be used twice. Then, place it in the sequence $4\choose2$. Then choose the base not to be used $3\choose 1$, and place the other two $2\choose 1$. So, our answer is $4\cdot6\cdot3\cdot2=144$. The internet solution is just an absolute mess and should be ignored.

Comment: $144$ looks good.  An alternate computation:  Chose the duplicate, $4$ choices.  Place the duplicates, $\binom 42=6$ choices.  Populate the first empty slot, $3$ choices.  Populate the second empty slot, $2$ choices.  Hence $4\times 6 \times 3\times 2=144$.  i can't follow the official solution.

Comment: The second calculation is just garbage  , it makes no sense it just throws numbers at the wall.

Answer (score 3):

There are four ways to exclude a base.
There are three choices for which of the remaining bases shows up twice.
There are $4!/2$ ways to arrange $4$ items when $2$ of them are identical.
Given that, there are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{24}{2} = 144$ ways.

Check: let's do the cases removing G. There should be $36$ of them.
Let's say the A is doubled. There should be $12$ of those:

With AA together:
AACT

AATC

CAAT

TAAC

CTAA

TCAA

With AA separated:

CATA

TACA

ACTA

ATCA

ACAT

ATAC

Answer (score 3):

The [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\left\{n \atop k\right\}$ counts the number of partitions of an $n$-set into exactly $k$ parts, so $k! \left\{n \atop k\right\}$ is the number of surjections of an $n$-set onto a $k$-set.  Your desired count is hence
$$\binom{4}{3} 3! \left\{4 \atop 3\right\} = 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 144.$$

Comment: While technically correct given the language the question uses I doubt they will understand what on earth is a "surjection of an n-set onto a k-set".